# Order Items Collection in Order Detail Page

Tags: magento2, collection, order-items

[image]

This snapshot of order detail page. I Just want to known that which file or function call for setting this collection in this page.
I want to just get Selected (Filter Row) Items Order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the assigned block to render the order items defined in layout file `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml`

`<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">`

`Block method \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items::getItemsCollection()` responsible for serving order item data to this page template.

You can get an idea to filter order item data on that collection in order model:

\Magento\Sales\Model\Sales::getItemsCollection($filterByTypes = [], $nonChildrenOnly = false);

Comment: MageAj ? You say absolute right  `Block method \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items::getItemsCollection()` is responsible for Items Collection. I override this block. i change the function `public function getItemsCollection()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getItemsCollection()->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('eq'=>1));
    }`
it return the same result. don't filter the collection. same result as i mention snapshoot in Question.  in sales_order_item a custom_attribute is save named "current_seller_id" and has value 1 But is not filter the result kindly check

Comment: Dear MageAj ! I did it by this `public function getItemsCollection()
    {
        //return $this->getOrder()->getItemsCollection();
        $Items_order=$this->getOrder()->getItemsCollection();
        $filter_order_items=[];
        foreach ($Items_order as $Items)
        {
            if($Items["current_seller_id"]==1){
                $filter_order_items[]=$Items;
            }
        }
        return $filter_order_items;
    }`

It filter absolute right. 
But i don't why `addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('eq'=>1));` don't know work. `foreach` loop work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

```
Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items:getItemsCollection
```

Is the method for getting items for section,If you want to MOdify that item collection then you  have  to work on that method

Comment: Yes it function responsible for items collection. But when i apply filter, it not filter the collection. I Have column named "current_saller_id" in sales_order_item.
Check it why not apply filter.
`public function getItemsCollection()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getItemsCollection()->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('eq'=>1));
    }`